# Show that a sequence is monotonic.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I have tried to solve this problem, but I am stuck. So, I have to show that sequence $a_n$ is monotonic from certain N. The sequence $a_n$ satisfy condition that:
$a_n < \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}{2}$ for $n \geqslant 2$.
After transforming the inequality, I got this: $a_n - a_{n-1} < a_{n+1} - a_n$. I don't know which direction to go next. Can anyone suggest anything?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?  Consider $a_n = (n-5)^2$. Does it satisfy the condition? Is it monotonic?

Comment: My professor gave me in order to practice. Now I see, it satisfy condition but it is not monotonic. There must be some mistake, I'll talk with him. Thank you.

Comment: @Macavity The mistake was that I forgot that in the task should be "monotonic from a certain N".

Comment: By your inequality, either $a_n -a_{n-1}$ is always negative, or it is eventually positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a_n = (a_n - a_{n-1}) + a_{n-1}$.

There are two cases here. In one of them, $(a_N - a_{N-1}) \ge 0$ for some $N$. What can you then say about the tail of the sequence from the $N$th term onwards i.e. $a_N, a_{N+1}, a_{N+2}...$?

What is the other case? Can you finish the reasoning from here?

Comment: The other case would be $a_N - a_{N-1} \leqslant 0$, I presume. If there is no N such that these two cases are possible, then sequence is constant?

Yes, I think I can finish, (in these tow cases, I'll use induction to show that for all n, starting from N, the sequence is monotonic). 

I'm curious, where can I use fact that $a_n = (a_n - a_{n-1}) + a_{n-1}$?

Comment: Your idea is very close, but it overlaps with the first case; the other case is $a_N - a_{N-1} < 0$ and *for all* $N$. Note that these cases cover every possibility. Constant sequences (and eventually constant sequences) are in the first case. To finish off the reasoning, remember what you're trying to prove. What is the definition of monotonicity?

Comment: Monotonicity means that for every natural n, the next element of sequence is not greater(lower) than previous. 
I want to prove that starting from some N, the sequence is monotonic for every n. 
In first case, i.e. $a_N \geqslant a_{N-1}$, I'll prove by induction that for every $n \geqslant N, a_n \geqslant a_{n-1}$ 
In second case i.e. $a_N \lt a_{N-1}$, I'll prove by induction that for every $n \geqslant N, a_n \lt a_{n-1}$ Correct?

Comment: @artobjective Correct :-)